# Several fragments app with split screen fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app with ONE Activity and match parent container for fragments. I use Jetpack Navigation. Everything works like a charm but one of my fragments should be split screened with half screen with RecyclerView and half screen with other views. Should I make ANOTHER activity for that? Or should I make fragments inside fragments somehow? I mean, how to make just ONE of my fragments split screened while parent activity have match parent fragment container.
Sorry for bad English.

Nothing much just asking about architecture

Comment: You mean, you need to implement a fragment with half screen with recycler view and half with other widgets like button, textfield etc? if yes you can use your same fragment to split view into two using layout constraints

Comment: @GeneralTony I mean I have all my fragments bound to only ONE Activity and that Activity have MATCH PARENT fragment container, so I can only make match parent (full screen) fragments, as I have 5 full screen fragments - it's ok, but now I need another fragment with half screen RecyclerView and half of other stuff. Yes, I can split that fragment into two parts with RV and other stuff on other part BUT then how can I make dynamic change of right half of screen when I click on recyclerview elements on the left side?

Comment: You could achieve what you want by using two fragment containers, one for all of your fragment, one for showing recyclerview fragment only. when you want to show the recycler view, you could visible that 2nd container which was in gone mode, and adjust both container height and constraints dynamically.